# Execute command every 1 second during loop in PERL

Tags: perl

I have to execute command each second during a loop **IN PERL**. I'm trying the following sample code using epoch time, but it doesn't work because it prints continuosly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
my $checktime = time() + 1;
while(1) {
    if ( $checktime => time() )
    {
       print "This should be print each second..." . "\n";
       $checktime = time() + 1;
    }
    # DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

I cannot use sleep or freeze commands because during loop I have to execute other commands without interrupt the execution.
Could you please help me?

Thank you,
Lucas

Comment: What other commands do you have to execute concurrently? Do you have to execute them from the same process?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with this condition, but if you just need it to 'print every second', consider using `sleep(1)`. You'll have to `use Time::HiRes`

Comment: If you are doing multiple things from the same process, you should consider using some event loop.

Comment: Thanks for partecipate to my question, as explained below, Is hard to explain what the "DO SOMETHING ELSE" do, since there is complex long code during loop. However, in few words. I connect to a server, open a file containing data, then loop through that file to read data. My goal is simple count how many data the loop send on each second. That's why I cannot use SLEEP function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` condition is bogus, `=>` is not "greater or equal" operator, and comparing times are reversed,

```
my $actiontime = time();
while (1) {
    if ( time() >= $actiontime )
    {
       $actiontime += 1;
       print "This should print each second...\n";
    }
    # DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Comment: `$actiontime += 1` should be `$actiontime = time + 1` in case `DO SOMETHING ELSE` takes multiple seconds. As it stands, that would result in a flurry of output to get `$actiontime` to catch up with the current time.

Comment: $actiontime increment is intentional in order to avoid time drifting. Both approaches are "wrong" but in different ways; it largely depends on what OP is expecting.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect, at least will print the output each second. Is hard to explain what the "DO SOMETHING ELSE" do, since there is complex long code during loop. However, in few words. I connect to a server, open a file containing data, then loop through that file to read data. My goal is simple count how many data the loop send on each second. I notice it sends about 100 packets per second, but I need to store that data!